# Generating Java Exceptions from XSD / binding Exceptions with JAXB2

Tags: java, exception, web-services, xml-serialization, jaxb

For webservices we usually generate java beans with the maven-jaxb2-plugin and use JAXB2 marshalling in Spring. I am wondering how to handle (SOAP-)faults that are declared in the WSDL/XSD best. In the application I would like to use Java exceptions that are marshalled to the faults. Is this possible? I haven't found a way to generate exceptions with the sourcecode generation of the maven-jaxb2-plugin. Thanks!

Update: I'd like to use spring-ws. But I guess the main problem is how to generate java exceptions with jaxb2 source generator.

Answer (score 0):

XFire (now CXF) lets you bind SOAP excpetions declared in the WSDL to particular Java exception as described [here](http://xfire.codehaus.org/Fault+and+Exception+Handling).  These Java exceptions are hand created through, not generated via JAXB.  I don't know if there's an equivalent in Spring-WS.

Answer (score 0):

Jaxb2-plugin generates beans from XSD only. You can use `jaxws-maven-plugin` instad of  `maven-jaxb2-plugin`.

**Try using this:**

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-from-wsdl<
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <configuration>
        <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl/</wsdlDirectory>
        <keep>true</keep>
        <sourceDestDir>target/generated-sources/wsimport</sourceDestDir>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Just simply invoke command `mvn clean install`, you'll find generated resources in `target/generated-sources/wsimport` on two packages:

- **types**-generated java beans same as from jaxb
- **wsdl**-classes, exceptions, interfaces generated from wsdl