# Quickstart tool for Spring-Webservices?

Tags: java, web-services, spring-ws

Now, working with Spring-WS, I sometimes miss the simplicity of working with axis, where you just call a tool on the WSDL and XSD, and it creates the java objects and marshaller configurations, an interface that represents the information in the WSDL, a complete webservice client that implements this interface, and a server stub. Within minutes you can start writing the actual code for the webservice.

With Spring-WS you have much more configuration work to do - you have configure a marshaller, an endpoint, code all the information in the WSDL manually, and using the soap faults from the WSDL in form of java Exceptions seems [difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070422/generating-java-exceptions-from-xsd-binding-exceptions-with-jaxb2). Is there any tool that simplifies this work to a similar degree? I understand and appreciate that Spring-WS is flexible and whatnot, but sometimes you just want to whip up a quick webservice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the quick-and-easy tooled approach, then Spring-WS is not for you. It emphasises flexibility, small footprint and runtime simplicity, at the expense of having a bit more to do at first.

If this isn't what you want, then stick with the more heavyweight stacks like CXF or Axis2.

Comment: It is not that it is impossible to write a tool that makes it easy to create some initial configuration and code for Spring-WS. It's just a pity if nobody did so far.

Answer (score 0):

It's explained on this page: [Why Contract First?](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/why-contract-first.html). Basically, since there are problems to be solved when starting from a WSDL, they have chosen to drop the ball. If you want to work from a WSDL and keep being integrated with Spring, then choose CXF.

Comment: Thanks, but strangely I haven't found anything on this page about problems with the WSDL. Except perpaps that they say you don't need a WSDL and that spring can actually generate a WSDL for you from the configuration. OK, that would be another way if you want to quickly implement a webservice, but not a solution if you really go contract first, as they recommend.

Comment: That page tells that they don't want to generate Java classes from a XSD, and since WSDL describe the messages in terms of XSD, then they don't want to support generation from WSDL at all.